# How to import, configure and run an existing project from GitHub in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, configuration, project

I downloaded a git project zip from: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view but I have trouble properly configure and run it in Android Studio.

I have a device configured in Android Virtual Device Manager, and I would like to load, configure and run the downloaded git module and related sample code on that device.

In the past I used MS Visual Studio. Managing projects seem much smoother in VS.

I tried to "Import project from external model", but couldn't create the proper configuration and run the sample.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the project then open Android Studio.
Next step is go to File->Open and then go to that folder where you have saved that github project and done.
Android studio will do everything for you.